# How to Optimize below linq query

Tags: vb.net, performance, linq, optimization

I have below Linq query in vb.net it is taking 2-3 min for 3000 records. I want to optimize it. Please suggest me

```
Dim sessionsEligibleForDeletion As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
```

**Below query is taking long time.**

```
sessionsEligibleForDeletion = 
    (From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
        Group row By sessionID = row.Field(Of Int32)("sessionID") Into SessionGroup = Group
        Select New With 
        {
            sessionID,
            .eligibleForDeletion = SessionGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("sessionID")) > totalCriterias - 1
        }).
            Where(Function(rr) rr.eligibleForDeletion = True).
            Select(Function(rr) rr.sessionID).ToList()
```

Comment: What does the databases query plan look like?  (Ie. the query might be reasonable with sensible indexes.)

Comment: What is `distinctReportNo`? Also, this is Linq-To-DataTable which is a  subset of Linq-To-Objects. If you could filter in the database that would be probably the most efficient approach.

Comment: i have updated question plz have a look. its not related to database.its just related to datarow and data table

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? First you select all reportNo from the table and then you select all rows which have a reportNo in this list. That are all rows since you are using the same source. So the first two queries are already pointless.

Comment: yes you are right..but the last query in which sessionsEligibleForDeletion is getting field is taking time...want to optimize that.

Comment: The first two queries are already taking a lot of time and are completly redundant. I also don't understand the `eligibleForDeletion` property in the anonymous type. This should not compile: `SessionGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("sessionID"))` because `Enumerable.Count` takes a `Boolean` predicate and not an `Integer`. Do you have `OPTION STRICT OFF`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter.. query is working fine..output is coming.but this query taking much time.want to optimize it.

its taking boolean i am further putting where and select with true

Comment: @Rajinder: yes, it's taking boolean but you are using `SessionGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("sessionID"))` which is clearly an `System.Int32`. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @TimSchmelter.. thanks for suggestion. i am selecting the row which are true.mean the row which match the count ...but  how to optimize it ?

Comment: @Rajinder: still not clear. `sessionID` is the key that you use for the `GroupBy`, so every group contains exactly one unique `sessionID`. It's pointless to count them. And the boolean predicate in `Enumerable.Count` is not satisfied by passing an integer anyway. Try to explain in words when a `DataRow` is eligible for deletion or provide a meaningful sample. Then we can try to provide an efficient approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter    .. with group by we can have different sessionID for each group..thats why m doing count....if count is greater than condition ,eligible for deletion will be true othervise it will be false....so i am selecting true further which are matching my count condition

Comment: @Rajinder: you are grouping all rows by the `SessionID` into a group named `SessionGroup`, these groups contain `DataRows` and every row has the same `SessionID` because you have grouped by that column. That's why i don't understand the `SessionGroup.Count(...sessionID)`. Maybe you just want to use `SessionGroup.Count() > totalCriterias - 1`, so without a predicate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter..yes you are right..but its giving me expected result..lets see with example

i have session id 
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3

its giving result ..with count condition=3

1  True
2   False
3   True

Comment: @Rajinder: maybe it gives the desired result because `Option Strict Off` forces some weird conversions(f.e. `1` = `True`). But you should really set `Option Strict` to `On` as default for every project.

Comment: @TimSchmelter
 its already on 
Option Explicit On

Comment: @Rajinder: `Option Explicit` is something completely different, it just forces you to declare every variable whereas `Strict` forces you to program in .NET instead of VB6. Both should be `On`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter.. thanks for detailed info.. could you please suggest me how to improve its execution ..any alternate way to optimize ,.i want to make it fast.

Comment: @Rajinder: so you want to find all `SessionID` which appear more than `totalCriterias - 1`?

Comment: i have remove tow statement and now replaced rowMatchingCriteria with dt.AsEnumerable()

Comment: @TimSchmelter.... now i just want group by sessionID and count of sessionID is greater than something

Comment: @Rajinder: note that i've edited my answer to provide also a LINQ query whichis not as efficient as the loop but might be efficient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `dt` is a `DataTable`, start by using `AsEnumerable` instead of `DataTable.Select` which returns a new `DataRow()` with all rows to save memory.

More important,  you select all `reportNo` from the table and then you select all rows which have a reportNo in this list. That are all rows since you are using the same source. So the first two queries are already pointless.

Also, you are grouping all rows by the `SessionID` into a group named `SessionGroup`, these groups contain `DataRows` and every row has the same `SessionID` because you have grouped by that column. That's why i don't understand the `SessionGroup.Count(...sessionID)`. That won't compile with `Option Strict` set to `On` anyway, because `Enumerable.Count` takes a boolean predicate instead of integer. Maybe you just want to use `SessionGroup.Count() > totalCriterias - 1`, so without a predicate.

Now to your actual performance issue. You want to find all `SessionID` which appear more than `totalCriterias - 1`? Then this simple loop using a `HashSet(Of Int32)` and a `Dictionary(Of int32, Int32)` would be more efficient, only one enumeration is needed:

```
Dim sessionsEligibleForDeletion As New HashSet(Of Integer)
Dim sessionIdCount As New Dictionary(Of Int32, Int32)
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim sessionID = row.Field(Of Int32)("sessionID")
    Dim count As Int32
    sessionIdCount.TryGetValue(sessionID, count)
    count += 1
    sessionIdCount(sessionID) = count
    If count > totalCriterias - 1 Then sessionsEligibleForDeletion.Add(sessionID)
Next
```

If you need a `List(Of Int32)` from the hashset use `sessionsEligibleForDeletion.ToList()`.

If you insist on a LINQ query you could use this:

```
Dim sessionsEligibleForDeletion As List(Of Int32) = dt.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("sessionID")).
    Where(Function(grp) grp.Count() > totalCriterias - 1).
    Select(Function(grp) grp.Key).
    ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..by removing directly two unnecessary statement and directly using dt in Linq,,it has optimized a lot. 





    sessionsEligibleForDeletion = (From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                   Group row By sessionID = row.Field(Of Int32)("sessionID") Into SessionGroup = Group
                                                   Select New With {